# How to test components using Mobx stores with Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mobx, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test my React components using Mobx stores with Jest and React-testing-library.

The problem is that I have no clues on how to inject my stores for the test.

Here is my simplified codes.

**StaffInfo.js(component)**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { observer, inject } from "mobx-react";

const StaffInfo = props => {
   const store = props.instituteStore;
   const [staffs, setStaffs] = useState(store.staffs);

   return (
      <div>
         ....
      </div>
   );
}

export default inject(rootStore => ({
    instituteStore : rootStore.instituteStore
}))(observer(StaffInfo));
```

**index.js(Root store)**

```
import LoginStore from "./LoginStore";
import InstituteStore from "./InstituteStore";

class RootStore {
    constructor(){
        this.loginStore = new LoginStore (this);
        this.instituteStore = new InstituteStore(this);
    }
}

export default RootStore;
```

**InstituteStore.js(target store)**

```
import { observable, action } from "mobx";

class InstituteStore {
    constructor(root){
        this.root = root;
    }

    @observable
    staffs = [];
}

export default InstituteStore;
```

**StaffInfo.test.js(test file)**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "mobx-react";

import StaffInfo from "./StaffInfo";
import InstituteStore from "../stores/InstituteStore";

describe("Staff Component testing", () => {
    test("should be rendered without crashing", () => {
        const div = document.createElement("div");
        ReactDOM.render(
            <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/staff"]}>
                <StaffInfo instituteStore={RootStore.instituteStore} />
            </MemoryRouter>,
            div
        );
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
    });
});
```

As soon as running this test file, the error messages are like :

```
TypeError : Cannot read property 'staffs' of undefined
```

Please tell me which parts of the codes are wrong.
Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: use `Provider` from `mobx-react` in your app.js to pass the mobx stores to deeply nested childs

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I've already used `Provider` in my app.js. Do I have to declare app.js in my test to pass the stores?

Comment: After trying several things, I've finally figured out that declared codes like `<Provider {...root} ><App><StaffInfo /></App>` in my test file work well. You saved my day. Thank you so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Mobx-react`'s `Inject` is used to insert stores to the deep child component. These stars are provided by the context-based API `Provider`.

so wherever you are providing the stores to the child components use something like.

```
import rootStore from 'path_to_rootStore'
<Provider rootStore={rootStore}>
...
... 
 <App/>
...
...
<.Provider>
```

Comment: Legend! Finally someone gave a sensible answer :D
This is what My component looks like and ```@inject('routing', 'navigationStore')
@observer
export default class PageTitle extends React.Component<*> {...}```
And this is how I made it work:
```let view = mount(
      <Provider {...getStores()}>
        <UserPage notificationStore={notificationStore} routing={routing} />
      </Provider>
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @uneet7:

Legend! Finally someone gave a sensible answer :D
This is what My component looks like and

```
@inject('routing', 'navigationStore')
@observer
export default class PageTitle extends React.Component<*> {...}
```

And this is how I made it work:

```
let view = mount(
      <Provider {...getStores()}>
        <UserPage notificationStore={notificationStore} routing={routing} />
      </Provider>
    );
```

So the **UserPage** has components (many) and one of those components has **PageTitle** component. Obviously PageTitle has the @inject on it. It doesn't matter, as Provider HOC will provide stores via `inject` function to the component props.